# How to include mutable "tags" for classes in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on writing a small application in Python 3 and would appreciate some advice on overall structure. I have a collections of objects of a custom type, let's call them objects of the `file` class. I would like to be able to associate "tags" to each of these objects. Each object can have zero, one, or more than one tag associated with them. I would like to implement these tags in such a way that:

- I can easily retrieve a list of all objects with a given tag associated with them
- These tags can be easily modified - the user should be able to change tags, add new ones, etc.

The best solution I currently have is to create a list for each tag which contains all objects corresponding to that tag. This easily satisfies the first bullet point, and also makes it easy to create new tags and change them. However, this solution involves making multiple copies of the same object if it has more than one tag associated with it, which seems unnecessary. This could be solved with pointers, but my understanding is that this wouldn't work in Python. Are there other ways of structuring this data in Python that would accomplish what I'm trying to do?

To include some example code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class file:
    # Defines other attributes of the class

# Initializes files

file1 = file()
file2 = file()
file3 = file()

# Defines tags for files

tagA = [file1, file2]
tagB = [file3]
tagC = [file1, file2, file3]

# The things that I want to do with these tags:
# Print all files with a certain tag

print(tagC)

# Removes a tag from a certain file

tagA.remove(file1)

# Make a new tag

tagD = [file2, file3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting an object in a list doesn't make a copy. It's more like a reference. Here's a super simplified example:

```
>>> obj = object()
>>> a = [obj]
>>> b = [obj]
>>> id(a[0]) == id(b[0])
True
```

BTW, you might prefer to [use a dict instead of variable variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/4518341).

Comment: Just what I was about to say :)

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful. Can you explain what you mean by variable variables though? I read the link you referred to (and its corresponding links) and I believe I understand the concept, but I don't understand how this is relevant to what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Henry Right, yeah I should clarify. Your tags should support arbitrary names, right? But if you wanted to create a tag called `class`, for example, you couldn't, cause that's a keyword in Python. On the other hand, if you use a dict, you can create a key with the string `'class'` and it will work.